# How to display a value from snap on DialogFlow fullfilment using Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make an intent to display info that is stored on Firestore.

This is my DB.
[image]

I would like to display "definicion" value.

This is my Intent on Js (usingNodejs):

```
    app.intent('my.def.intent', (conv) => {
    // Trying to get Data from firestone DB,
        var platformRef = db.collection("plataformas").doc("slack");
        var getDef =  platformRef.get()
        .then( snap =>{
            var dat = "";
            if (snap.exists) {
                dat =  snap.data("definicion");
            }
             return dat;
        })
        .catch( err => {
            console.log("error...", err);
        });
    // This is the response for Actions on Google
    conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
                  speech:"This is the def: " + getDef,
                  text:"This is the def: " + getDef,
                }));
    });
```

This code makes a display on the ActionsOnGoogle Simulator something like this:

**This is the def: [objecto Promise]**

I don't understand whats happenning here . Why i cant display the info from "definiciones" and instead that, there is an [object promise]? how can i display the info?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call to platformRef.get().then( ... ) is asynchronous and returns a Promise, so when you access the value of getDef, its value is a Promise.

To fix it you should put the `conv.ask` code inside of your `.then` block above. However, since you already have access to value of `snap` inside, you won't really need the value of `getDef` and can use `snap` directly. Finally, you'll need to return the value of that promise from your intent function. Putting this together gives:

```
app.intent('my.def.intent', (conv) => {
   // Trying to get Data from firestone DB,
   var platformRef = db.collection("plataformas").doc("slack");
   return platformRef.get()
            .then( snap => {
              var dat = "";
                if (snap.exists) {
                  dat =  snap.data("definicion");
                }
               // This is the response for Actions on Google
               conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
                  speech:"This is the def: " + dat,
                  text:"This is the def: " + dat,
               }));
           })
           .catch( err => {
             console.log("error...", err);
           });
 });
```

I suggest taking a look at the official sample - [dialogflow-updates-nodejs](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-updates-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js). It also uses Firestore and can help with coding.